# Prettier eslint: use 'prettier' or 'plugin:prettier/recommended' with React Typescript airbnb eslint config

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb, prettier-eslint

In my React Typescript project I updated `prettier`, `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `eslint-config-prettier` to latest version. I am also using `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript`.

I have below in the extend property inside `eslintrc.js`:

```
extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    // "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    // 'plugin:prettier/recommended', <- Should I add this?
    // 'prettier' <- or this?
  ],
```

I am confused after reading the [changelog](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800-2021-02-21). Should I use `prettier` or `plugin:prettier/recommended` in the *extend* property inside `eslintrc.js` eslint config?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use `plugin:prettier/recommended`.

From [recommended configuration](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#recommended-configuration), it mentioned that `plugin:prettier/recommended` expands to

```
{
  "extends": ["prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "off"
  }
}
```

We can see that the `extends` array contains `prettier`. I think you don't need to add it again.

Answer (score -3):

plugin:prettier would do the trick @meez.

Comment: This is not correct. I get this back from terminal:
"plugin:prettier" is invalid syntax for a config specifier.

* If your intention is to extend from a configuration exported from the plugin, add the configuration name after a slash: e.g. "plugin:prettier/myConfig".